# recommended way to install mongodb on elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have already taken a look at [How to install mongodb in Elastic Beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653625/how-to-install-mongodb-in-elastic-beanstalk) dated 2014, which no longer works. as well as https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/#manually-deploy-mongodb-on-ec2

I have set up a new elastic beanstalk environment running on node.js with 1 ec2 micro instance '64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.0 running Node.js'

I have already tried using ssh to connect into my instance and install the mongodb packages using yum command:

```
$ sudo yum install -y mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
```

and received this call back:

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No package mongodb-org-server available.
No package mongodb-org-shell available.
No package mongodb-org-tools available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

When I first ssh 'd into my instance, I received this error warning:

```
This EC2 instance is managed by AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Changes made via SSH 
WILL BE LOST if the instance is replaced by auto-scaling. For more information 
on customizing your Elastic Beanstalk environment, see our documentation here: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html
```

Currently my environment is set up as a single instance environment, to save on costs. However, in the future I will upgrade to an auto-scaling environment.

Because of this, I am asking is it recommendable to make any changes via ssh in ec2, or should I only be using EB CLI?

I have both EC2 and EB CLI installed locally, however I have never used EB CLI before. If I should be using EB, does anyone have a recommended way to install mongodb?

Comment: You do not want to install a database on Elastic Beanstalk. You shouldn't even be making any changes via ssh to your EB environment at all. Do you not realize that EB will add and delete servers from your environment automatically? New servers it adds won't have your changes, and old servers with things like databases running will be deleted and you will lose everything. Read my answer to this question for the right way to use MongoDB with Elastic Beanstalk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837610/elastic-beanstalk-deployment-with-mongodb

Comment: Yes, I realised that. That's why I explained I am currently running a single server app, however I wanted to know recommendable installation for when I upgrade to auto scaling. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In case anyone is looking for an answer, here is the advice I received from aws business support.

All code deployed to Elastic Beanstalk needs to be "stateless" I.E. Never make changes directly to a running beanstalk instance using SSH or FTP.... As this will cause inconsistencies and or data lose!
- Elastic Beanstalk is not designed for application that are not stateless. 
The environment is designed to scale up and down pending on your Network / CPU load and build new instances from a base AMI. If an instance has issues or the underlying hardware, Elastic Beanstalk will terminate these running instances and replace with new instances. Hence, why no code modification must be applied or done "directly" to an existing instance as new instances will not be aware of these direct changes. ALL changes / code needs to be either uploaded to Elastic Beanstalk console or the CLI tools and the pushed to all the running instances.
More information on Elastic Beanstalk design concepts can be read at the following link
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.concepts.design.html

Suggested Solution:
With the above in mind, if using MongoDB to store application data our recommendation would be to DE-couple the MongoDB environment from your Node.js application.
I.E Create a MongoDB Server outside of Elastic Beanstalk, example launching MongoDB directly on a EC2 instance and have your Elastic Beanstalk Node.js application connect to MongoDB Server using connection settings in your app.

-Creating MongoDB 
Below is some example links that may be of use for your scenario for creating a MongoDB Server. 
Deploy MongoDB on EC2,
https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/
MongoDB node client
https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/node/client/
MongoDB on the AWS Cloud quick start guide
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/architecture.html

-Adding environment variables to Elastic Beanstalk to reference your MongoDB server
Once you have created your MongoDB Server you can pass the needed connection settings to your Elastic Beanstalk environment using environment variables. 
Example using .ebextensions .config  which you can add Mongo URL / ports / users etc..

option_settings:
 - option_name: MONGO_DB_URL
   value: "Your MongoDB EC2 internal IP address"

Information on how to use environment properties and read them from within your application can be seen below. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.container.html#create_deploy_nodejs_custom_container-envprop
And information using .ebextensions .config can be found at the following link
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

Alternatively you can also set environment variable using the cli or via the AWS Console 
eb cli set environment variables can be read per the below link.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-setenv.html
Using AWS Console 
To set system properties (AWS Management Console)
   Open the Elastic Beanstalk console.
   Navigate to the management console for your environment.
   Choose Configuration.
   In the Software Configuration section, choose Edit.
   Under Environment Properties, create your name / values ...

Accessing Environment Configuration Settings
Inside the Node.js environment running in AWS Elastic Beanstalk, you can access the environment variables using process.env.ENV_VARIABLE similar to the following example.
process.env.MONGO_DB_URL
process.env.PARAM2

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.container.html#create_deploy_nodejs_custom_container-envprop

Summary:
In summary I would recommend the following steps to integrate MongoDB with Elastic Beanstalk environments. 
Step 1) Create a MongoDB Server outside of Elastic Beanstalk
Step 2) Create your Node.js application in Elastic Beanstalk that connect to your MongoDB server

Comment: Unfortunately, the amazon business support missed a vital reason why you would want mongo installed on the same server as the app server; to utilize mongoDB clusters, it is recommended that application servers each run a mongos (not plural but literally "mongo s") instance to act as a proxy. The OPs original question is still valid and would be interesting to know what the officially support method for handling this would be.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961046/mongos-install-setup-in-elastic-beanstalk/33448970) provides additional details on doing it with config files. (That allow for automatic service restarts/ installations) - You will need to modify for MongoDB version appropriate for your instance

Answer (score 0):

### 3 options:

1) SSH into an eb instance and install the mongo CLI manually:

```
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2013.03/mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/
sudo yum install --nogpgcheck -y mongodb-org-shell
```

Disadvantage is that if EB scales down its number of instances and the instance you are currently on gets terminated, you get kicked out of the SSH session:

```
The system is going down for halt NOW!
Connection to 1.2.3.4 closed by remote host.
Connection to 1.2.3.4 closed.
ERROR: CommandError - An error occurred while running: ssh.
```

You then need to start all over again: connect to instance, install mongo CLI...

2) Pre-install mongo CLI on instances by using a `.config` file:

```
container_commands:
  01-mongocli:
    command: "sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2013.03/mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/;sudo yum install --nogpgcheck -y mongodb-org-shell"
    ignoreErrors: true //use this the ensure instance deployment even if mongo CLI installation fails
```

Again, if the instance gets terminated by auto-scaler you'd have to connect again, but you don't have to the install mongo CLI manually.

3) Create a separate instance that hosts your mongo CLI, as described in @amyloula's answer. If your mongodb is within an VPC you need to create that separate instance also within the VPC. You will then need to create a Gateway to access the instance publicly, as you cannot connect directly to an instance in a VPC.